# Kernelの一部を修正しようとmake menuconfigしたが、scripts/kconfig/zconf.lex.cでエラーがでる

Tags: c, kernel

kernelのソースコード（linux-5.0)をダウンロードして、make menuconfigやmake oldconfigを実行してみましたが、以下のようなエラーが発生します。*zconfig.lex.c*というファイルがないという話だと思うのですが、*zconfig.lex.c*とは、どのようなファイルでしょうか？また、どのようにして作成？すればよいのでしょうか？

```
 LEX     scripts/kconfig/zconf.lex.c
/bin/sh: 1: flex: not found
scripts/Makefile.lib:193: recipe for target 'scripts/kconfig/zconf.lex.c' failed
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/zconf.lex.c] Error 127
Makefile:538: recipe for target 'menuconfig' failed
make: *** [menuconfig] Error
```

Comment: エラーメッセージに `/bin/sh: 1: flex: not found` とありますので、flex コマンド(fast lexical analyzer generator)をインストールする必要があります。お使いのLinux distribution が何なのか分かりませんが、例えば Ubuntu Linux では `sudo apt install flex` などとします。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージのこの部分が大事です。

```
/bin/sh: 1: flex: not found
```

つまり、[flex コマンド](https://github.com/westes/flex)が見つかっていないというエラーです。zconf.lex.c というファイルが見つからないというエラーではありません。`recipe for target 'scripts/kconfig/zconf.lex.c' failed` というのは zconf.lex.c のための make が失敗したというログで、その理由は flex が見つからなかったからですね。

flex は[字句解析器](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AD%97%E5%8F%A5%E8%A7%A3%E6%9E%90)のひとつで、お使いの OS やパッケージマネジャーに合わせた方法でインストールできます。たとえば Ubuntu であれば `sudo apt install flex` など。

Comment: 解決しました。どうもありがとうございました。